# why is my input inserted into two diff arrays with same index? (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, insert

I have this js script which works perfectly as a battleship and I want to change the script because right now I have to manually add the number of ships in even though locations are generated randomly.
At this moment, I have to add in ships this way.

```
ships: [{locations: ["", "", ""], hits: ["", "", ""]},
        {locations: ["", "", ""], hits: ["", "", ""]},
        {locations: ["", "", ""], hits: ["", "", ""]}],
```

I modified the script so now it's `ship: []`

Somehow with the new script when a location is entered and the location is hit, it hits all objects with the same hit index.

I will provide the working script which worked perfectly and the script I added.

***Working Script***

```
var model = {
    boardSize: 7,
    numShips: 3,
    shipLength: 3,
    shipsSunk: 0,
    ships: [{locations: ["", "", ""], hits: ["", "", ""]},
            {locations: ["", "", ""], hits: ["", "", ""]},
            {locations: ["", "", ""], hits: ["", "", ""]}],
    fire: function(guess){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.numShips; i++){
            var ship = this.ships[i];
            var locations = ship.locations;
            var index = locations.indexOf(guess);
            if(index >= 0){
                ship.hits[index] = "hit";
                view.displayMessage('You hit my ship');
                view.displayHit(guess);
                if(this.isSunk(ship)){
                    view.displayMessage("You sunk one of my ship!");
                    this.shipsSunk++;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        view.displayMessage("You missed!!!~!~!~!");
        view.displayMiss(guess);
        return false;
    },
    isSunk: function(ship){
        for (var i = 0; i < this.shipLength; i++){
            if(ship.hits[i] !== "hit"){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    generateShipLocations: function(){
        var row, column;
        var direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        if(direction === 1){
            row = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.boardSize);
            column = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.boardSize - this.shipLength));
        }else{
            row = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.boardSize - this.shipLength));
            column = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.boardSize);
        }

        var newShipLocations = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.shipLength; i++){
            if(direction === 1){
                newShipLocations.push(row + "" + (column + i));
            }else{
                newShipLocations.push((row + i) + "" + column);
            }
        }
        return newShipLocations;
    },
    generateShip: function(){

        var locations;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.numShips; i++){
            do{
                locations = this.generateShipLocations();
            }while(this.collision(locations));
            this.ships[i].locations = locations;
        }
    },
    collision: function(locations){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.numShips; i++){
            var ship = model.ships[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < this.shipLength; j++){
                if(ship.locations.indexOf(locations[j]) >= 0){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
};
```

I added one function into the model, modified the `generateShip()` and `ships`

```
ships: [],

generateShipProps: function(){
    var emptyStrings = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.shipLength; i++){
        emptyStrings.push("");
    }

    for(var j = 0; j < this.numShips; j++){
        model.ships.push({locations: emptyStrings, hits: emptyStrings});
    }
},

generateShip: function(){
    this.generateShipProps();

    var locations;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.numShips; i++){
        do{
            locations = this.generateShipLocations();
        }while(this.collision(locations));
        this.ships[i].locations = locations;
    }
}
```

For the working script ships would look something like this when loaded

```
ships: [{locations: ["10", "11", "12"], hits: ["", "", ""]},
    {locations: ["22", "23", ""24], hits: ["", "", ""]},
    {locations: ["51", "52", "53"], hits: ["", "", ""]}],
```

if location entered is correct let's say 10 then the array in the hits property will input a string of "hit" like below

```
ships: [{locations: ["10", "11", "12"], hits: ["hit", "", ""]},
    {locations: ["22", "23", ""24], hits: ["", "", ""]},
    {locations: ["51", "52", "53"], hits: ["", "", ""]}],
```

for the modified script `ships` property would still produce something like this

```
ships: [{locations: ["10", "11", "12"], hits: ["", "", ""]},
    {locations: ["22", "23", ""24], hits: ["", "", ""]},
    {locations: ["51", "52", "53"], hits: ["", "", ""]}],
```

but let's say if `11` is entered, this would happen

```
ships: [{locations: ["10", "11", "12"], hits: ["", "hit", ""]},
    {locations: ["22", "23", ""24], hits: ["", "hit", ""]},
    {locations: ["51", "52", "53"], hits: ["", "hit", ""]}],
```

somehow it's implementing hits into all the same index.

Can someone give me a hand what I have missed that's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

replace this code

```
locations = this.generateShipLocations();
```

with this:

```
locations.push(this.generateShipLocations());
```

and you will also need to initialize locations like this:

```
var locations = []
```

you are overwriting instead of adding

Comment: this would just crash the browser :(